# Let a supervisor die if a child exits

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

(Note: I'm still learning, and the following may thus be a completely stupid architecture)

I'm building a simple TCP server in Erlang. I have a hierarchy that starts a supervisor for each peer connection, which in turn oversees a multiplexer, a socket reader and a socket writer.

Now of course when the client socket closes, all four (supervisor, mux, reader, writer) should exit, as it doesn't make sense for them to stay around. The reader/writer do note when the socket closes and exit, but the supervisor still hangs around.

How do I setup the supervisor so that this happens?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the supervisor's "maximum restart frequency" to zero, meaning that the supervisor will crash if any of its children crashes.  The `init` function of the supervisor module would look something like this:

```
init(Args) ->
    Multiplexer = #{id => multiplexer, start => ...},
    Reader = #{id => reader, start => ...},
    Writer = #{id => writer, start => ...},

    Flags = #{intensity => 0},
    {ok, {Flags, [Multiplexer, Reader, Writer]}}.
```

For cases like this, when a supervisor supervises processes that are tightly coupled and should be restarted together, you'd normally use the `one_for_all` restart strategy, but here it doesn't matter since you just want the entire thing to crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the reader/writer set to restart => temporary, which seems to prevent the supervisor from crashing when those children exit (for any reason). Now I've set restart => transient, which seems to work now.